# a single variable acting as multiple parameters in bash?

Tags: bash

How to split a single variable into multiple arguments?

In fish shell, one can use

```
set my_var (echo 'line1
line2
line3' | string split '\n')

./my_command $my_var
```

this is equivalent to

```
./my_command line1 line2 line3
```

so a single variable acting as multiple parameters, how to do that in bash shell?

Comment: You typically would  create an array out of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If arguments are separated by newlines:

```
#!/bin/bash

my_var='line1
line2
line3'

mapfile -t args <<< "$my_var"
./my_command "${args[@]}"
```

`args` is an array name here (it can be any other valid name). `mapfile` reads lines into the array (named `args` here). `"${args[@]}"` expands array elements as a list.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `mapfile`, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

my_var="line1 line2 line3"

mapfile -t argv <<< "${my_var/ //$'\n'}"

./my_command "${argv[@]}"
```

---

If the variable has embedded newlines, try

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

my_var='line1
line2
line3'

mapfile -t argv <<< "$my_var"
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, many times you don't need a variable at all. If you don't need to iterate over the tokens multiple times or compare them to the adjacent ones or etc, just loop over the values directly.

```
while read -r value; do
    : something with "$value"
done <<____HERE
    first value
    second one
    third goes here
____HERE
```

Or to adapt to your specific example

```
./my_command "line1" "line2" "line3"
```

or if you really need a loop,

```
for value in "line1" "line2" "line3"; do
    : something with "$value"
done
```

A variable you only interpolate once is often just a waste of memory. If it helps readability or configurability, it's a small price to pay; but many beginner scripts seem to be riddled with completely unnecessary variables.